# Renaming a Field for JSON output

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

So I have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
         public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
 }
```

I need to make it email_address before i add it in the body of my request

I tried:

```
[SerializeAs(Name = "email_address")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

but it doesn't work. any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed , I used

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email_address")] 
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```